# More accurate clockwise vertices sorting

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, vertices

I've used few algorithms for clockwise vertices sorting and still can't sort as it should be sorted.

The poly is always square with cutted off smaller squares of same size (let's name them chunks). So say I have square 6x6 and chunks are 1x1. More specifically: square has vertices: [0,0], [5,0], [5,5], [0,5].
If I'll cut the chunk off at position [0,0] (like intersection done with smaller square on vertices from [0,0] to [1,1]), square looks like this:

[image: Beautiful chunk intersection]

His vertices are now: [0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [5,0], [5,5], [0,5]

It's fine. But let's do some more intersections. I won't show second intersection of chunk at position [1,0] because there is all fine. Now if I'll do third intersection, say at position [0,1] it looks like this:

[image: Ugly intersection]

Of course, it should look like this:

[image]

So as You can see, it's just sorting fail which sorts vertex [1,2] before [0,2]

I'm wonder if it will sort good when I'll add something like checking the distance from centroid. Well.. Here is a code of this sorting:

```
function (a, b) {

    var distance1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x - centroid.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - centroid.y, 2));
    var distance2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b.x - centroid.x, 2) + Math.pow(b.y - centroid.y, 2));
    var a1 = Math.acos((a.x - centroid.x) / distance1);
    var a2 = Math.acos((b.x - centroid.x) / distance2);

    if (a.y > centroid.y)
        a1 = Math.PI + Math.PI - a1;

    if (b.y > centroid.y)
        a2 = Math.PI + Math.PI - a2;

    return a1 - a2;

}
```

and centroid:

```
function (vertices) {
    var 
        x = 0,
        y = 0,
        pointCount = vertices.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < pointCount; i++){
        x += vertices[i].x;
        y += vertices[i].y;
    }

    x = x/pointCount;
    y = y/pointCount;

    return new vec2(x, y);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `centroid` in your examples? Is it expected?

Comment: Based on code `centroid` should be at [2, 2]

Comment: Well in that case there's no wonder why [1,2] sorts before [0,2] - both have the same angle to the centroid and could be placed in either order. You'll need to choose better algorithm for locating the center you want to sort around, not change your sorting.

Comment: Implemented new algorithm for centroid, was good but unfortunately still bugging in some cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've implemented new function after clockWise sorting, that is angle optimization. Whole algorithm works like this:

[image: super algorithm]

If there are any sugestions, please feel free

here is the code for angle optimization:

```
for (var i = 1; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        var a = vertices[i - 1];
        var b = vertices[i];
        var j = i;

        do {
            var distanceAngle = Math.abs(Math.atan2(a.y - b.y, a.x - b.x));
            if (
                distanceAngle == Math.PI / 2 ||
                distanceAngle == Math.PI ||
                distanceAngle == 3 * Math.PI / 2 ||
                distanceAngle == 2 * Math.PI ||
                distanceAngle == 0
            )
            {
                var tmp = vertices[i];
                vertices[i] = vertices[j];
                vertices[j] = tmp;
                break;
            }
            j++;
            b = vertices[j];
        } while (j < vertices.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really check whether there are any bugs in your comparison function, but it's overcomplicated. You can just use [`Math.atan2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) to get the angle between two points. Your function should look like

```
function(a, b) {
    return Math.atan2(a.y - centroid.y, a.x - centroid.x)
         - Math.atan2(b.y - centroid.y, b.x - centroid.x);
}
```

Comment: I had sorting like this and believe me or not, my actual function sorts better this square's vertices